# I want to remove right padding from a list of div

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove the right padding from the class="no-border". I tried the below CSS however, I am not able to do so. I tried "padding-right:none" but nothing is happening.

```css
#menu-bar-container-2 { border: 1px solid gray; }

.menu-bar-2 a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px 0px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px #bb4545 solid;
}

.no-border {
  border-right: none !important;
  padding: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-bar-container-2">
  <div class="menu-bar-2">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">War in Ukraine</a>
    <a href="">Coronavirus</a>
    <a href="">Climate</a>
    <a href="">Video</a>
    <a href="">Asia</a>
    <a href="">UK</a>
    <a href="">Business</a>
    <a href="">Tech</a>
    <a href="">Science</a>
    <a href="">Stories</a>
    <a href="">Entertainment & Arts</a>
    <a href="">Health</a>
    <a href="" class="no-border">More</a>
    <img src="images/Down Arrow.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve] and added a border to the container div to show the edge but it wrapped. Maybe post an image of what it looks like and your expected result too?

Answer (score 0):

`padding-right: none;` is invalid value property.

Change it to `padding-right:0;` or to `padding:0;`

`border-right: none;` is correct and valid.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS padding syntax:**
`padding: length|initial|inherit;`
So padding value must be either length or initial or inherit.

- **length:** length specifies the padding in px, pt, cm, etc. *[length can be use as percent (%) also]*
- **initial:**  Set the padding to its default value.
- **inherit:** Set the padding from its parent element.

So, padding has no `none` value. You can use either of these. Try `padding-right:0px;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change padding right to 0px
padding: 2px **0px** 0px 16px;

```
   .menu-bar-2 a {
      float: left;
      color: black;
      padding: 2px 0px 0px 16px;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-right: 1px #bb4545 solid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you can't use `none` value for padding you can write  `padding-right:0;`